# Books and techniques to hedge options that expire tomorrow?

Tags: options, hedging, delta-hedging

Can anyone point me to books or resources that talk about best techniques to hedge ATM or close to ATM options that expire tomorrow.  I am particularly interested on how to hedge if you are short the option.

Thanks!